# Make div behave as image

Tags: html, css

How can I make a div's sizing properties behave exactly like they do for image tags, if the div's background is an image?

The idea is to duplicate the way an image tag behaves in this code snippet:

```css
div{
  background-color: #2DBCFF;
  text-align:center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size:0;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px; height: 150px; line-height: 150px;"><!-- <<<CSS props controlled
 and changed with JS

--><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o23xS.jpg"><!--

--></div>
```

---

#### NOTE :

the div's height and width properties are changed with JS

**FOR CLARITY :**

I want the CSS properties width, height, max-width, and max-height properties behave the same as if the div tag was an image tag. (aspect ratio preserved, size of div is based on image, etc...)

Comment: What do you mean? Behave how?

Comment: width, height, max-width, and max-height properties behave the same in relation to the image

Comment: So you want to use width and height of image and set it as width and height of div and also set that img as background of that div?

Comment: yes with concerns to aspect ration, but with max height and max width props

Comment: Somewhat similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css).

Comment: @DaMaxContent Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/65/? You enter image url with data attr and it takes width and height and sets it as `max-width` and `max-height` of div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a lot of modification done to this faux `img` (`.imgDiv`), the reason why it's harder than it should be is because `img` is a replaced element and `div` is not, [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170210160818/http://richkode.me/something-about-css/) will explain the differences (author's second language is English, but the grammatical errors do not hinder comprehension.)

**Example 1. & 2.** The following are the original `img` (`.control`) and  `.imgDiv`:

```
// Example 1. `.control`: `position: relative` was added for demo purposes.

  .control {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .imgDiv {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; 
    background-position: center;
  }
```

- Background Properties

  - [background-image](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-image/)
  - [background-repeat](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-repeat/)
  - [background-size](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/)
  - [background-position](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/)

In short, if you want to mimic a replaced element, you should use a replaced element. What determines a replaced element's dimensions is not itself, but what it has (ie content of an `img` would be a png file), a non-replaced element is not determined by it's content (ie div). So I figured a `video` element would be a more suitable `img` replacement.

**Example 3. & 4.** A quick breakdown:

```
 // Do not copy this code, I broke it into pieces so you don't have to scroll

 <div class="case" style="width:300px; height: 150px; line-height: 150px;">

  <video id="vid1"

     poster="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" 

     width="300" height="150"></video>

</div>

// Do not copy this code, I broke it into pieces so you don't have to scroll

<video id="vid2"

   poster="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png"

   src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs8s3.mp4" 

   width="100%" height="auto">

</video>
```

- **Attributes**:

  - poster: This attribute accepts a path to an image then displays the image until the `video` element plays. Without going any further, we can see that the`video` element can stand in for `img` easily.
  - controls: They are removed since we are only interested in the image aspects of the `video` element.
  - src: I assigned this attribute a small video (86.6KB). I don't think we need it, I just added it in for testing.
  - width and height: A [`video` element](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) by itself can be responsive just by setting width to 100% and height to auto.

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/P2SyxGhSwISCKmbt5AW5?p=preview)

**Snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>35522592</title>
  <style>
    body {
      counter-reset: exp;
    }
    span.txt:before {
      counter-increment: exp;
      content: "Example " counter(exp)". ";
    }
    .box {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-table;
      min-width: 300px;
      min-height: 150px;
      margin: 5% auto;
    }
    .case {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #2DBCFF;
      text-align: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: 0;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    .control {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .imgDiv {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: center;
    }
    .big {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    .txt {
      margin: 0 0 15px 20px;
    }
    #vid1,
    #vid2 {
      fit-object: contain;
    }
    #b2 {
      background: #F06;
      min-width: 40vw;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="box">
    <div class="case" style="width:300px; height: 150px; line-height: 150px;">
      <img class="control" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png">
    </div>
    <span class="txt">This is the image<b class="big">&#8679;</b> from the OP.</span>
    <div class="case" style="width:300px; height: 150px; line-height: 150px;">
      <div class="imgDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="txt">This div <b class="big">&#8679;</b> uses the property background-image.</span>
    <div class="case" style="width:300px; height: 150px; line-height: 150px;">
      <video id="vid1" poster="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" width="300" height="150"></video>
    </div>
    <span class="txt"><b class="big">&#8679;</b>This is a video  element it only has an image, no video.</span>
  </section>

  <section class="box" id="b2">
    <video id="vid2" poster="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs8s3.mp4" width="100%" height="auto"></video>
    <span class="txt">This is a video  element <b class="big">&#8679;</b>it has an image and a video.</span>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the link to the article is no longer working. do you have another one? and can you please take a look at my (similar) question? thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60167477/align-the-bottom-of-a-child-element-with-the-parents-baseline/60175226

Comment: Here is the article: https://web.archive.org/web/20170210160818/http://richkode.me/something-about-css/

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean is that the `div` width and height change with respect to the aspect ratio like the image then you can rely on CSS by using `padding` like this:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding-bottom: 50%; /* Aspect ratio of the width/height */
}
```

No JS needed.

Comment: I have looked into that. Problem: max-width needs to be width of parent element like it was for the image tag in my snippent. Also, does not use max-height property.

Comment: Then change `max-width` to be 100% ... This will make it the same width of the parent.

Comment: max-height is still an issue.