# Align the bottom of a child element with the parent's baseline

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, baseline

I would like to vertically align a child element in a flex box (or text box) so that its bottom coincides with the baseline of its siblings.

This happens by default for images:

[MDN <img> Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Styling_with_CSS):

> <img> has no baseline, so when images are used in an inline formatting context with vertical-align: baseline, the bottom of the image will be placed on the text baseline.

Can I achieve the same effect with a <div> instead of an <img>?

**Later edit:** I'm attaching a snippet. I want the bottom border of the last child to coincide with the bottom border of the image (the *baseline* of the rest of the children). I *don't* want everything aligned to the bottom.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}

.child2 {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 200%;
}

img {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.child-bottom {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #fdd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span>These</span>
    <span class="child2">are</span>
    <span>baseline</span>
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9">
    <span>aligned.</span>
    <div class="child-bottom">This child's bottom border should be on the baseline of the parent.</div>
</div>
```

**Later edit 2.** A picture is a thousand words. Hope it helps clarify what kind of alignment I need. Notice how letters j, p, and q extend below the baseline.  [image: bottom to baseline]

Comment: Have you tried using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) ?

Comment: of course I tried, also searched stackoverflow from top to bottom:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution:) It was hidden somewhere in the CSS specification:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

This is taken from https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align, bottom of the page.

So, in order to move its **baseline** to the **bottom margin edge,** you only have to add `display: inline-block` and `overflow: hidden` (or anything other than 'visible', eg: 'auto') to the child element:

```css
body {
    font-size: 200%;
}

.bottom {
    display: inline-block; /* <--- this */
    overflow: hidden; /* <--- and this */

    width: 10rem;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>text jklmnopqr</span>
    <div class="bottom">div with bottom on the baseline</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're my hero here - a great question, and an obscure find to answer the question!

Answer (score 1):

So I have not found a good solution for your question, but I give you what I've tried, maybe it will give you some ideas.

Apparently, the baseline alignement with flexbox only align the text content as you want, not the div itself.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: last baseline;
}

.child2 {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 200%;
}

img {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.child-bottom {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #fdd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span>These</span>
    <span class="child2">are</span>
    <span>baseline</span>
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9">
    <span>aligned.</span>
    <div class="child-bottom">This child's bottom border should be on the baseline of the parent.</div>
</div>
```

But an empty div will be aligned on baseline ?

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}

.child2 {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 200%;
}

img {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.child-bottom {
    padding: 5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #fdd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span>These</span>
    <span class="child2">are</span>
    <span>baseline</span>
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9">
    <span>aligned.</span>
    <div class="child-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried solutions with absolute positionning, but you are forced to define the size of the parent, which is not a good solution...

The best solution I found is, I think, to align the text with flexbox, then translate the block with the size of your padding... I hope it helps you a little bit...

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: last baseline;
}

.child2 {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 200%;
}

img {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.child-bottom {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #fdd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    transform:translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span>These</span>
    <span class="child2">are</span>
    <span>baseline</span>
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9">
    <span>aligned.</span>
    <div class="child-bottom">This child's bottom border should be on the baseline of the parent.</div>
</div>
```

Another solution would be to align everything with flex-end so that every child are aligned at bottom but I guess it is not what you want as you said already.

Comment: thanks for researching:) it's interesting that an empty div is aligned with its bottom on the baseline. i'll try to leverage that somehow.

Answer (score -1):

I created a simplest example.

```css
.parent{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end

}
.child{
  background: red;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: fit-content
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>some text</div>
  <div  class='child'>some more text</div>
  <div  class='child'>some more more more more more more more more text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: to learn more about flex:check  https://flaviocopes.com/flexbox/

Comment: sorry, but I only want _one_ of the children to be aligned with its bottom on the same line as the rest of the children's baseline. you aligned everything at the bottom: that's not what I want.

Comment: Thanks @Manon, I did my research, I know about "align-self", I'm not aware of any value for that property that answers my question.